# Insert multiple items in List before inserting into database

Tags: c#, sql-server, list, ado.net

So I have the relation in the database as follows:

[image]

The idea is to add multiple product categories into the list before inserting it into the database.

I'm using ADO.NET framework, and the mapped class products contains list of product categories. So when the user fills out the form that is needed for product category I say:

```
Products p = new Products(... initializing);
ProductCategories p2  = new ProductCategories(...initializing);
p.ProductCategories.Add(p2);
```

What I don't understand is how to add more of these ProductCategories items into this list before I insert them into the database. Whenever I add new one, the old one seems to be deleted from the list, and I don't understand why? The order should be like this:

1st product category item
2nd 
3rd...

(If the user stops adding them....) -> click save button -> insert all product categories from the list into product categories table...

Instead of that I just get overwritten old product category with new values that I just inserted. Can someone help me out with this??

EDIT: here is the entire code responsible for adding multiple items to the list

```
       if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null && FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        p = new Product();
// p is declared as property outside of all methods...
                        p.ProductName =  txtProductTitle.Text;
                        p.Dimensions = ".";
                        p.PricePerUnit = float.Parse(txtProductPrice.Text);
                        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);
                        MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
                        img.Save(mem, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                        p.ProductPicture = mem.ToArray();
                        p.ProductPicThumb = mem.ToArray();
                        p.MeasurementUnitID = int.Parse(dropMeasure.SelectedValue);
                        p.PricePerFeet = 1.2F;
                      int pid =  ServiceClass.InsertProduct(p);
        ProductCategories p2  = new ProductCategories(...initializing);
        p.ProductCategories.Add(p2);
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Product successfully added!');</script>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Something went wrong!');</script>");
                    }
```

Comment: need more info, working code etc. are you recreating your list each time?

Comment: looks like you db has 1 to many products to categories when really you want many to many

Comment: add a new table Product_ProductCategory ProductId, ProductCategoryID

Comment: I might do that ,but how to insert multiple items in list before inserting them into db, thats the main question lolz..

Comment: @BerndLinde I've fixed it, thats not thecause of the problem. I will paste now the entire code... P.S. I've edited the main question with the entire code...

Comment: I've added the entire code now...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75202/discussion-between-perkes456-and-ewan).